# GDB remote debugging from Mac to Linux truncates memory locations

Tags: macos, gdb, 32bit-64bit, remote-debugging

I installed GDB on macOS 10.13.3 using [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49222683/how-do-i-install-gdb-on-macos-10-13-3-high-sierra).

I can use `gdb` locally without any hiccups, but remote debugging is a different story.

Fortunately, I am able to set remote breakpoints and they catch and return the correct line of code. However, when I try to print the variables, I am getting bad addresses.

It appears `gdb` is truncating the address space from 64-bit to 32-bit (i.e. truncating `0x71fe12345678` to `0x12345678`).

Is there a setting in GDB that will allow it to correctly access the 64-bit memory address space of the remote machine?

> ***NOTE:** The remote target is `gdbserver v8.1` on Alpine Linux in a Docker container running on the host.*

Comment: "Is there a setting ..." -- `gdbserver` is supposed to tell GDB appropriate register size automatically. Your question lacks relevant details: in particular, what is your remote target.

Comment: @EmployedRussian updated post with your request

Comment: Should gdbserver be the same version as gdb (8.0.1)?