# gdb opens but breaks on the "start" command every time

Tags: c++, macos, gdb

I just spent the last couple hours trying to figure out how to get gdb to work on MacOS. I finally got it and have the ability to run files within the shell, but even the simplest files cannot run properly. I am just trying to run a "hello world" file called hello.cpp. I know that the file runs fine outside of gdb.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

To compile the program I run `$ g++ hello.cpp -o hello -g`. To run the shell, I have to give sudo permission `$ sudo gdb`. Once in the shell I try to use the 'start' command `(gdb) start`. I always get one of three results from running this series of commands.

```
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x100001056: file hello.cpp, line 5.
Starting program: /Users/mllax8/Desktop/Embedded/Embedded_Labs/lab0/hello 
[New Thread 0x1103 of process 1639]
[New Thread 0xe03 of process 1639]
During startup program terminated with signal ?, Unknown signal.
```

or

```
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x100001056: file hello.cpp, line 5.
Starting program: /Users/mllax8/Desktop/Embedded/Embedded_Labs/lab0/hello 
[New Thread 0x1003 of process 1625]
[New Thread 0xe03 of process 1625]
During startup program terminated with signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
```

or 
It just gets stuck after the [New Thread… line and must be manually aborted

The same 3 errors seem to occur when I use `run` as well. What could this be?

Comment: Probably, it's a duplicate. You need a new version of gdb. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49222683/how-do-i-install-gdb-on-macos-10-13-3-high-sierra

Comment: i reinstalled gdb hours before posting using homebrew, do you mean I have duplicate gdb?

Comment: What is the version of the gdb?

Comment: I just checked and its 8.3.1

Comment: Try `gdb v8.0.1`, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49222683/how-do-i-install-gdb-on-macos-10-13-3-high-sierra.